# ActiveMQ Static Network : How do I drop messages when disconnected?

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I have a very simple static network.  Broker A is always running and always sending messages on topic X.  Broker B is statically configured to connect to Broker A, and has a consumer of topic X.

B may not always be able to reach A.  When B reconnects to A, it receives a burst of messages which occurred when they were disconnected.  I do NOT want these messages.  I've been researching and experimenting for two days now and cannot find a configuration that throws out the messages that occur during the periods where they are disconnected.  Can someone please point me in the right direction as to how to configure my brokers?  Much appreciated.

Comment: Seems like you are using durable subscription, but you don't want to.

Comment: I know, right?  I double and triple checked, but everything is standard, non-durable.  I finally seem to have solved my problem by modifying the prefetch value.  I'll update now to reflect this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that prefetch was the culprit in my case.   Specifically, in the xml configuration of Broker B, I added a prefetchSize="1"  to the networkConnector.  I am no longer seeing the burst of messages on reconnect.